# I want to draw polygon inside google maps using latitude and longitude in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

how to draw polygon in google maps using react native .I have a array list of latitude and longitude I want to draw polygon inside google maps using latitude and longitude .

Comment: you can use [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps)

Comment: yes how to draw polygon inside google maps

Comment: read the document of the given library, you will get everything

Comment: can u share me the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Answer

```
<MapView>
    <Polygon
        coordinates={[
            { latitude: 37.8025259, longitude: -122.4351431 },
            { latitude: 37.7896386, longitude: -122.421646 },
            { latitude: 37.7665248, longitude: -122.4161628 },
            { latitude: 37.7734153, longitude: -122.4577787 },
            { latitude: 37.7948605, longitude: -122.4596065 },
            { latitude: 37.8025259, longitude: -122.4351431 }
        ]}
        strokeColor="#000" // fallback for when `strokeColors` is not supported by the map-provider
        strokeColors={[
            '#7F0000',
            '#00000000', // no color, creates a "long" gradient between the previous and next coordinate
            '#B24112',
            '#E5845C',
            '#238C23',
            '#7F0000'
        ]}
        strokeWidth={6}
    />
</MapView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the docs for said package, Polygon component accepts an Array of coordinates to draw it.

Should be around these lines where your state is an array of coordinates.

```
<Polygon coordinates={this.state.coordinates}/>
```

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/polygon.md

Comment: I am new to react native I am not getting how to use

Comment: please reply for my question

Comment: Could you send me what you currently have and we work from there?